# Searching for a combination of characters in a file

Tags: c, file-io

I am trying to create a program that reads a file and searches for a specific combination of characters. 
For example: "/start/ 4jy42jygsfsf /end/".

So I want to find all the "strings" starting with /start/ and ending with /end/.

In order to do that, I use read() function because the file might be a binary file (it doesn't have to be a file with chars).

I call the read() function like that:

```
#define BUFFSIZE 4000

// more declarations

while (read(file_descriptor, buffer, BUFFSIZE) > 0)
{
    //search for /start/
    //then search for /end/
    //build a string with all the chars between these two
    //keep searching till you reach the end of buffer
}
```

Assume that every /start/ is followed by an /end/.

The question is:

How do I deal with cases that this combination of characters is cut in half?

For example, let's say that the first time read() gets called, in the end of this buffer I spot **/star** and the next time read() gets called at the start of the second buffer there is **t/ 4jy42jygsfsf /end/**.

This combination might get cut anywhere. The solutions I thought will result to many many lines of code. Is there any smart way to deal with all these cases?

Answer (score 0):

When you reach the end of the buffer, record the state of the current partial match, if any.  Then when you get the next buffer, you have 4 general cases:

- Not inside any text to be matched.
- Saw just a beginning `/` at the end of the last buffer
- Currently inside `/start/`.  Another variable records how far you have matched.
- Currently inside `/end/`.  Same variable as for `/start`/ records how far you have matched.

Your states inside the matcher are generally:

1. Currently not matching anything
2. Just saw a `/` - next looking for an 's' or an 'e'.
3. Matching either `start/` or `end/`.
4. Matched - either `/start` or `/end`.

Based on the partial match, just jump to the right state in the matcher.

OR

You can use the [PCRE library](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2api.html).  It supports partial matching.  But probably is overkill for your purposes.